# Label above a left arrow in tikz

Tags: labels, tikz-cd

I need to label a left arrow in tikz, but it labels the left arrow automatically under the arrow, which looks ugly. How do I make it label above?

Codes:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
        X_{\overline{s}} \arrow[r,"\tilde{j}"]\arrow{d}
        & X_{\widetilde{S}} \arrow{d}
        & X_{\widetilde{\eta}} \arrow[l,"\tilde{i}"]\arrow{d}
        \\
        X_{s} \arrow[r,"j"]
        & X 
        & X_{\eta }\arrow[l, "i"]
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome. In the future, please always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: @SandyG Thanks for the guideline! I will do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `'` to the letter label that you want to put on top.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
        X_{\overline{s}} \arrow[r,"\tilde{j}"]\arrow{d}
        & X_{\widetilde{S}} \arrow{d}
        & X_{\widetilde{\eta}} \arrow[l,"\tilde{i}"']\arrow{d}
        \\
        X_{s} \arrow[r,"j"]
        & X 
        & X_{\eta }\arrow[l, "i"']
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Several ways:

1. Add `'` after the arrow label: `\arrow[l, "i"']`
2. Add the `swap` option: `\arrow[l, "i", swap]`
3. Draw the arrow from the previous cell pointing right, but with `leftarrow`: `\arrow[r, "i", leftarrow]`
4. Same as 3 but using `<-`: `\arrow[r, "i", <-]`